# CryptoKitty birth and auction clock

Tags: cryptokitties, scheduling

How does CryptoKitty implement scheduling functions such as give birth function or auction ending function.

I tried to track it through Eth Fiddle but didn't find how it was done. Is there a function that calls itself every block mined and makes all the necessary checks whether the birth time or auction time is up?

I wanted to know because I wanted to do something similar, I want to create an auction and after a certain duration, the object would go to its highest bidder automatically.

I looked into Ethereum Alarm Clock but it seems a little unstable at the moment and doesn't seem to be live on main net either.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

[Ethereum Alarm Clock](https://www.ethereum-alarm-clock.com) is live on main net and stable. There was more than 1000 ETH moved through its protocol. It was also security audited.

Here is tutorial how to schedule transaction: https://medium.com/@MyCrypto/schedule-your-ethereum-transactions-now-on-mycrypto-92a6305f7dcc

It is integrated in [MyCrypto](https://mycrypto.com) (toggle 'Send Later').

Answer (score 0):

In CryptoKitties, there is no scheduling of functions. Rather, the birth function or auctionended function must be manually called via a transaction.

How do kitties get born on schedule then? Cryptokitties depends on people to call the birth function in a transaction. They charge a .08 ETH mating fee to provide incentive and offset the gas costs of whoever is calling that birth function. AxiomZen also ran a birth daemon that watches the chain and then calls the birth function on kitties ready to be born.